# If $A$ dense $A$ is not connected

Tags: general-topology

> Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be dense in $\mathbb{R}$ but $A\neq\mathbb{R}$, Prove: $A$ is not connected

a. can $A\neq \mathbb{R}$? by definition $A$ dense iff $\overline{A}=\mathbb{R}$

b. assume that it is possible, to show that $A$ is not connected I can find an set within $A$ which is open and close? is it sufficient?

Comment: a: The set of rational numbers is dense in $\Bbb R$, it's not equal to $\Bbb R$, and it's not connected.

Comment: There are lots of strict dense subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. See for instance $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$. Then indeed, if you manage to find a subset of $A$ that is closed and open in $A$, and different from $A$ itself and from $\emptyset$, then you are done.

Comment: So if I take $[1/n,1)\in \mathbb{Q}$ this will prove the claim?

Comment: You are working with $A$, and you a priori do not know what $A$ looks like. Referring to $\mathbb{Q}$ hence is pointless. Moreover, $[1/n,1)\in \mathbb{Q}$ is not a correct notation. $\in$ should be used of elements, and $\subset$ is used for subsets (and surely though,  $[1/n,1)$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$).

Comment: @newhere To find a subset of $A$ that is both closed and open in $A$ for the induced topology, and different from $A$ and from $\emptyset$, you should consider an element $x\in \mathbb{R} \setminus A$ (which you can do by hypothesis). Consider then the set $\{ a\in A, a>x \}$. Can you show that it is satisfying?

Comment: If $A\ne R$, then there a point x in R, not in A.  Part of $A \gt x$ is not connected with part of $A\lt x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ is not equal to $\mathbb{R}$ so pick $p \notin A$.
Then $U = A \cap \{x: x > p\}$ and $a \cap \{x : x < p\}$ are non-empty (a mild use of $A$ being dense in $\mathbb{R}$), relatively open in $A$ (clear) and their union is $A$, so
$A$ is disconnected.

Comment: I know you wrote it is clear, but why they are open? although close set will work too right?

Comment: @newhere Because they are the intersection of an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ with $A$. You hopefully do agree that $\{x: x > p\}$ is open in the reals? I don't understand what you mean by "although close set will work too"?